# How to overcome a career switch slip

Tags: software-industry, career-development, career-switch

As a SDE I am looking to motivate the company to make an investment in the areas I am good at. Is there any strategy I can follow to accomplish that? Inspired in this [article](https://www.themuse.com/advice/12-bossapproved-tips-for-creating-a-new-role-at-your-company) I believe I could start by proposing arguments like the following:

- The number of potentials clients
- The return of investment achieved by participating in low cost projects
- The utility of some personal projects I have already started
- Collaboration possibilities with the academia

---

Some acronyms:

- SDE: software development engineer, basically a software teste
- SDET: software development engineer in test, a software tester who also creates automation scripts for UI or API testing

Comment: I'm a bit confused, are you looking for the company to create a new role and board you, or are you looking for the company to make investments in your research fields?

Comment: @RandomUs1r: well, basically both. I am looking to move my field of work closer to my career (a way to overcome the paradox illustrated here: me.me/embed/i/21386917) and also to facilitate the creation of incentives to the researchers by starting an industry-academy collaboration.

Comment: @Joe Strazzere: I used the terms to express the difference between a manual tester and an automated one, the company also employs developers for the second role, so the definition might vary due to translation issues.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere and juanma (I take it by your username you are from a Spanish-speaking country :), I think that the word we are looking for SDET is Quality Assurance Engineer (QA), at least that's how it sounds a bit, and it's how I've usually translated similar roles from Spanish to English

Comment: Can it still be considered an engineering if little or no math is applied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any strategy I can follow to accomplish that? Inspired in
>   this article I believe I could start by proposing arguments like the
>   following:
>
> - The number of potentials clients
> - The return of investment achieved by participating in low cost projects
> - The utility of some personal projects I have already started
> - Collaboration possibilities with the academia

This looks like a good start.

You might want to:

- Discuss the size and types of investments that it would take to enter this new market successfully
- Discuss what role you specifically want to have
- Discuss the competitors in this market, their strengths, their weaknesses
- Discuss the future of this market, if it is growing, by how much

Be sure to emphasize the value to the *company*, and not so much the value to *you* personally.

Comment: This is gold, thank you Joe. How ever, you didn't mention anything about entrepreneurship, is it a feasible strategy to create my own product (e.g. library, plugin) and offer it to my employer? How mature should it be before I expose it? How do I convince the company to invest in an open source project?

Comment: Mmm... I see. Leaving aside the commercial intentions, and given that one of my goals is also to facilitate the interaction between industry and academy, I can still start an open source source DSP-QA project to call the interest of the people at my faculty and the people at my company.